# Point program without garbaging up alias (~/.bashrc)

Tags: bash, bashrc

What is the correct way to point to a program/script without passing the command through aliases in the bashrc?

For example:

I create a custom script *MyScript.sh*.
I wish to create a command that can be run globally from shell by typing `scripty`, which would point to my script (*MyScript.sh*).

Is there a way to accomplish this? (The only way I know is creating aliases) If there is a "more correct way" to do this I would appreciate knowing how.

Answer (score 1):

Add the folder where the script is to your PATH?
Use the full path to the script?

Comment: Please expand further. I would like to set it up so I can type just a regular command (like *scripty*). Are you saying to add to $PATH ?

Comment: Yes, add the directory where _MyScript.sh_ is to your path. Now just type _MyScript.sh_ and it'll execute.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the script in a directory that is already in your path. It is for example quite standard to have `/usr/local/bin` in PATH, so you could add your script to `/usr/local/bin`. if you don't have permission, then adding the scripts location to your path is your other option.